# this.props.children vs this.props.someName

Tags: reactjs, children

It seems, I see two equal ways to delegate property via props:

```
let App = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return (
          <Unit someName="Push me!" />
        )
    }
});

class Unit extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
          <button>
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"/>
            {this.props.someName}
          </button>
        )
    }
};
```

and

```
let App = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return(
          <Unit>
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
            Push me now!
          </Unit>
        )
    }
});

class Unit extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
          <button>{this.props.children}</button>
        )
    }
};
```

1. What's the general purpose of props.children?
2. Can I consider it as equal to props.someName?
3. Could be provided some examples where props.someName doesn't work but props.childred does?

Comment: To me, these use cases satisfy different requirements, and are **not** only related to transferring props.  `this.props.children` is a way of creating a *container* component that is wrapping children.  The props are not transferred.

Comment: May be I haven't got your point, Davin, but <Unit> is a child component. So, this.props.children doesn't create any container. In my case it just say:"Hey, I'm a children! So, I owe my parent property."

Comment: Excuse typo, it should be "I'm a child".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, but I think that the existence of children is just syntactic sugar to allow an HTML-like nesting of elements. As far as I know, it is exactly the same as any other property. In fact, while using JSX you can add children as an ordinary property and it doesn't make any difference.

```js
let App = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return(
            <Unit children={<span className="glyphicon glyphicon-heart">Push me now!</span>}/>
            )
    }
});

class Unit extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
        <button >{this.props.children}</button>
        )
    }
};
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Not correct example. It's actually this.props.someName. In your example children = someName

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, `this.props.children` is used to refer to *all* the children that are wrapped in a custom component.

```
<View>
   <Text>One</Text>
   <Text>Two<Text>
</View>
```

Here, the two `Text` elements are children to your `View`. In the class definition(or equivalent) for your `View` component, you can refer to all the children components by `this.props.children`. But I think you already understand this much.

From what I understand, as a rule of thumb, you pass some values/properties, etc as props to a component.

If you want to, for example, *render* some components in a custom component that you are defining, you need to be able to refer to what components were declared in the *implementation* code from *definition* code, so you use `this.props.children`.

My language is a bit muddled, but I hope this is clear enough.